# Double quotes in Jquery

Tags: jquery, double-quotes

I have read several posts regarding usinq quotes in jQuery and have not been able to form my own query.
I have to check a span tag for a particular string.  The string i am searching for is:  role="alert"        (it has double quotes around the word alert.

```
$("span:contains('role="alert"')").each(function() {        
        alert($(this).text());
    });
```

Can someone provide a query for this?

Comment: side note if you're looking for `<span>` elements with a `role="alert"`, using :contains(role...) won't work. You must do `$('span[role="alert"]')`. On a side note, always rap everything around with single quotes, using doubles only inside.

Answer (score 13):

```
$("span:contains('role=\"alert\"')")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use:

```
​$('span[role="alert"]')​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​.each(function() {        
    alert($(this).text());
});
```